# HTML form input not storing in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, input

So I am using a basic form called details that is asking for 4 basic types of user input.  The issue is that I cannot get this input to store within my js array.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <script src="store.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="cgi-bin/formmail.pl" method="post">
    Name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" size="25" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Date: <input id="date" type="date" name="date" value="" size="25" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Location: <input id="location" type="text" name="location" value="" size="25" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Category: <select><option value="landscape">Landscape</option>
    <option value="portrait">Portrait</option>
    <option value="conceptual">Conceptual</option>
    <option value="street">Street</option>
    <option value="fine art">Fine Art</option>
    <option value="people">People</option>
    <option value="abstract">Abstract</option>
    <option value="nature">Nature</option>
    <option value="architecture">Architecture</option>
    <option value="flower">Flower</option>
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="animal">Animal</option>
    <option value="children">Children</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Change details" onclick="insert()" />
</form>
    <div id="display">      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The js is as follows:

```
var nameinput = document.getElementById("name").value;
var dateinput = document.getElementById("date").value;
var locationinput = document.getElementById("location").value;

var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");

function insert() {
   var details = [nameinput, dateinput, locationinput];

}
```

I cannot figure out why this is not storing the input.  ALso is there anyway to save the users input from the select box? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to get the values from the inputs via their .value property *inside* your insert() function. (Your current code gets the values *once*, when the page first loads.) Regarding the select, give it an id and get its value the same way as for the input elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The reason your not able to save the value is because your getting the values from the input fields outside the click function is performed.You should try to get the value , after the click is performed.

2) You can get the selectbox value by giving it an id e.g category and getting its value

```
 var category = document.getElementById("category").value;
```

**See below code:**
I have placed the code , which gets the form value inside `insert()` function. And i have given `select box` an `id` as category and used the same id to retrieve the value. And have displayed the value stored inside `display div` using `innerHTML`.

```js
function insert() {
var nameinput = document.getElementById("name").value;
var dateinput = document.getElementById("date").value;
var locationinput = document.getElementById("location").value;
  var category = document.getElementById("category").value;

var messageBox = document.getElementById("display");
   var details = [nameinput, dateinput, locationinput,category];
  messageBox.innerHTML=details[0]+','+details[1]+','+details[2]+','+details[3];
}
```

```html
<form action="cgi-bin/formmail.pl" method="post">
    Name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" size="25" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Date: <input id="date" type="date" name="date" value="" size="25" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Location: <input id="location" type="text" name="location" value="" size="25" maxlength="50" />
    <br/>
    <br/>
    Category: <select id="category"><option value="landscape">Landscape</option>
    <option value="portrait">Portrait</option>
    <option value="conceptual">Conceptual</option>
    <option value="street">Street</option>
    <option value="fine art">Fine Art</option>
    <option value="people">People</option>
    <option value="abstract">Abstract</option>
    <option value="nature">Nature</option>
    <option value="architecture">Architecture</option>
    <option value="flower">Flower</option>
    <option value="general">General</option>
    <option value="animal">Animal</option>
    <option value="children">Children</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Change details" onclick="insert();" />
</form>
    <div id="display">      </div>
```